# Compare file and list to see if they are identical

Tags: python, list, file

I have a file containing the numbers 1-100 and a list with the same numbers. I'm having some problems with comparing them and checking if they are the same. 
This is my code so far:

```
f = open("tall.txt", "w")

for i in range(101):
f.write(str(i) + "," + " ")

f.close()


with open('tall.txt') as a:
    lines = a.read().splitlines()

tall = []

for i in range(101):
    tall.append(i)

for (i,t) in zip(lines,tall):
    if i != t:
        print("Does not match")
        break
 #else:
    print("Match")
    break
```

The problem I'm having so far is that if I print lines it starts with [' and ends with '], therefore not matching the other list.

How can I fix this? Is it an easier way to do the whole process?

Thanks.

Comment: does the order of the values matter? e.g. `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` are the same? If it doesn't matter, why not just do an array intersection?

Comment: Yes, the order matters. Want to check if they are in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splitlines()` reads your python files by considering `\n` or newline character as the delimiter. But the file that gets written at the first step of your program doesn't have `\n` after each number as the `match` logic expects. Hence the problem.

The following modified code works correctly. I removed the `,` and changed it to `\n` while writing into the file. Also the check condition `i!=t` should be `i!=str(t)`

```
   f=open("tall.txt", "w")

    for i in range(101):
      f.write(str(i) + "\n")

    f.close()


    with open('tall.txt') as a:
        lines = a.read().splitlines()

    tall = []

    for i in range(101):
        tall.append(i)

    for (i,t) in zip(lines,tall):
        if i != str(t):
            print("Does not match")
            break
     #else:
        print("Match")
        break
```